# Appcache update notify

Tags: javascript, html5-appcache

I am trying to do a notification to user when the appcache is modified and I found the guide here: http://appcachefacts.info/

```
if (window.applicationCache) {
    applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function() {
        if (confirm('An update is available. Reload now?')) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

The code does work. But the problem is that, when user first visit the webpage or clear their browser appcache, they will also receive the notification. This is something that I don't want.

How can I have the notification only appear when there is the new update? Not on the first visit or even after the appcache is cleared from browser.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809730/cache-manifest-manual-updates/30845904#30845904) question.